# Procedimiento almacenado MYSQL Error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure, prepared-statements

Buen día.
estoy haciendo un procedimiento almacenado que permite actualizar información en base al los parámetros que se le pasen el problema es que al llamar al procedimiento me arroja este error

> Call updateMasivo(1,'ARIEL','Nombre','machina') 1054 - Unknown column 'ARIEL' in 'field list'

pero ariel lo estoy pasando como una valor no como una columna este es el código del procedimiento:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE `updateMasivo`(id_tabla int(11), valor_columna varchar(20) ,columna_accionada varchar(20), table_name varchar(20))
BEGIN 
 SET @table_name = table_name;
 SET @columna_accionada = columna_accionada;
 SET @id_tabla = id_tabla;
 SET @valor_columna = valor_columna;
    
 SET @sql_text = concat('INSERT into ',@table_name,'(ID, ',@columna_accionada,')
    VALUES (',@id_tabla,', ',@valor_columna,')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ',@columna_accionada,' = VALUES(',@columna_accionada,')'); 
 PREPARE stmt FROM @sql_text; 
 EXECUTE stmt; 
 DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; 
 
 

END
```

Agradezco la ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu línea

```
concat('INSERT into ',@table_name,'(ID, ',@columna_accionada,')
    VALUES (',@id_tabla,', ',@valor_columna,')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ',@columna_accionada,' = VALUES(',@columna_accionada,')');
```

con los valores que pones te da como resultado:

```
INSERT INTO machina (ID, Nombre) VALUES (1, ARIEL) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Nombre=VALUES(Nombre)
```

Podrás notar que faltan coloques a `ARIEL` entre `'` para que sea cadena. Bueno espero haber armado bien con tus parámetros el resultado de lo que se esta intentando ejecutar y te genera el error.